# HazelCast FencedLock не всегда успешно блокирует метод для других нод

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация, lock, hazelcast

Решил `синхронизировать` метод между 2 нодами приложения. Для этого взял `FencedLock` решение из библиотеки `HazelCast`. Все сделал по документации, ноды друг-друга увидели и объединились в `кластер`. Метод тоже `синхронизировался`, начал отрабатывать по 1 разу, но время от времени происходит дубляж работы метода(не часто).

Не могу понять с чем это связано!
Проблему я решил тем, что создал распределенный объект `IMap`, который поместил внутрь метода и исходя из него стал либо отрабатывать метод, либо игнорировать. Мне кажется, это больше похоже на костыль.

Нет ли пути решения данной проблемы через `fencedLock`-и и его конфиги?

P.S. Просьба не ссылаться на какие-то ключевые слова и отправлять меня в `google`, так как документации крайне мало и нет примеров работающего кода. Буду благодарен развернутому ответу.

**hazelCast.yaml файл:**

```java
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
```

**HazelCastConfiguration класс:**

```java
@Configuration
public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public com.hazelcast.config.Config hazelCastConfig() {
        return new Config();
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config hazelCastConfig) {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public IMap<String, LocalDateTime> timeMap(@Qualifier("hazelcastInstance") HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return hazelcastInstance.getMap("hazelcastTimeMap");
    }
```

Над методом я повесил `Spring Scheduler` и настроил его `cron` на работу каждые 5 секунд.

**Метод до того как я добавил IMap:**

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")
    public void sentMessage() {
        FencedLock lock = hazelcastInstance.getCPSubsystem().getLock("myLock");
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("test message!" + LocalDateTime.now());
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

*Результат его работы между 2 нодами:*

**Нода 1:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нода 2:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*После добавление `IMap` и ориентирования по нему, проблему ушла.*

**Метод после добавления IMap:**

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")
    public void sentMessage() {
        FencedLock lock = hazelcastInstance.getCPSubsystem().getLock("myLock");
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                LocalDateTime date = timeMap.get("message");
                if (date == null || LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(date)) {
                    System.out.println("test message!" + LocalDateTime.now());
                    timeMap.put("message", LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(4));
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спринг, да и ОС, не гарантируют тебе одновременное исполнение `@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")` + тело метода маленькое и отрабатывает быстро.

В итоге, иногда получается, что на одном узле вызов по расписанию успевает взять лок, напечатать и отпустить лок. В этот момент до лока добирается второй, но лок никто не держит, поэтому второй тоже отрабатывает.

`IMap` как раз эту проблему решает. Решение не костыльное, а вполне нормальное.

По другому можно было бы сделать за счёт удержания лока подольше, чтобы второй узел успел проснуться, попытаться взять лок и обломиться. Например, `Thread.sleep(100)` - но это <strike>тоже</strike> не будет 100% гарантией, потому что второй может опоздать и на больше, чем 100мс - например, у него случился GC. Это даже по твоим логами видно - один раз исполнение в X.008ms, другой раз в X.171ms.

Comment: а что тогда будет 100% гарантией?

Comment: Твой `Imap` будет гарантией. Ещё можно организовать голосование между нодами, чтобы они выбрали лидера. Тогда в момент срабатывания расписания, каждый проверяет, лидер он или нет, и только лидер делает работу. Но по сравнению с `IMap` - это как из пушки по воробьям.